# undoing taskkill explorer.exe to show SYSTEM partition

Tags: windows-explorer

So I used taskkill to kind of elevate explorer.exe but I don't trust my family to not snoop in it. I want to save my laptop so how do I hide it/ restore explorer.exe to its normal state?
Commands used in CMD below.

```
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
explorer.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Using diskpart to select volume and removing letter helped.

```
In CMD:
diskpart

In DISKPART:
list disk
sel disk [Disk Index]
list vol
sel vol [Volume Index]
remove letter [Volume Letter]
```

[Disk Index], [Volume Index] and [Volume Letter] as required.